Efficiently generating Uniswap V4 hook address
Is there a way to efficiently generate Uniswap V4 hook address ?
I've looked into uniswap docs and some other tutorials online, however all of them are generating hooks' addresses with bruteforce.
In my case, using this approach just crashes https://remix.ethereum.org/ environment page after some time without the expected result.
Example of finding hook's address in the docs:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v4/concepts/hook-deployment#2-two-hooks
